# What's the intended purpose of the 'radio' tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I was performing a quick edit on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21035/how-to-tune-a-frequency-like-89-0-on-jusada-ics-cm7-stock-radio) and decided to see if we had a [radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) tag available since I know I've seen other questions around about streaming radio stations and such to devices. As it turns out, we do have such a tag, but it's being used to refer to both AM/FM/Internet radio stations and cellular radios. What's the intent of this tag, and how should it be appropriately used? There is currently no tag wiki to indicate the purpose.

My thoughts: Maybe we re-tag the questions about cellular radios with a new tag along the lines of [cellular-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-radio)? We do have [radio-firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-firmware), but I'm not sure that it's really correct for some of the questions regarding cellular radios (e.g. "How do I disable my 3G radio?" or similar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've removed [radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) completely and retagged questions when appropriate in the following ways:

- Anything about FM radio was retagged with [fm-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm-radio)
- Anything about internet radio streams was retagged with [internet-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internet-radio) (a new tag)
- Anything about the cellular radio in a device (but not the firmware necessarily) was retagged with [cellular-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-radio)

Since the above 3 tags will appear in the search suggestions when typing the string `radio` I'm not synonymizing it with any of them. If you see it resurface please feel free to retag as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create [fm-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm-radio) as well, retag the existing [radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) and [radio-firmware](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-firmware) questions as necessary, and make [radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) synonym to one of the tags (not sure which one should be most appropriate, probably [fm-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm-radio) since it's most commonly associated with "radio" out of context).

[cellular-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-radio) is also a good idea, although I am not a big fan of tag proliferation.

Comment: We can probably rename `radio` to the most prelevant one (and retag as neccessary to the other); I'd avoid having an ambiguous name like `radio` as a synonym if possible

Comment: @MatthewRead: The rationale for the synonym comes exactly from its ambiguity: new users will tend to search first for [tag:radio] if their question is about FM or firmware -- just the key word that comes to mind first. If the tag is to be resurrected anyway, it might as well be synonymized with one of the others and call it a day. These tags are a bad example since they have a common root, but hopefully you can see how this can be a problem if they were not.

Comment: It's highly unlikely for anyone to search `[radio]` unless the tag exists, which is different from searching `radio`.  Typing `radio` into the tag area of a question will result in anything containing that, e.g., `fm-radio`, being suggested.  Not having it shouldn't negatively impact search.