# Radio tag is ambiguous

Tags: discussion, retag-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the intended purpose of the 'radio' tag?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/whats-the-intended-purpose-of-the-radio-tag)

[radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) tag can refer both to radio ROM (the part that controls communications functions) and to FM radio. We already have a tag for the latter: [fm-radio](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fm-radio).